# Disable Office 365 Outlook Add-in for desktop

Tags: office365, office-addins, office-js, office365-apps, outlook-web-addins

I have developed an Office 365 Outlook Add-in for the web. It's automatically supported in desktop also. I want to disable the app only for the desktop. I guess we need to change something in Manifest file but I couldn't get any clue. Can anyone help me to achieve this??

Comment: I'm curious why you want to disable the app in Desktop? is there a reason your app is only applicable in OWA? If support for something like this is added, the dev team would need justification as to why a developer would need it.

Comment: I have developed Add-in in OWA using on-send event feature. If I deploy this add-in, then it is also available in Desktop which is not working because the on-send event in Desktop is different with the one in OWA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Office add-in is aim to cross-platform developing for the Office solution. At present, it doesn't support to limit platform. Here is the specification of “Host“ element which used to specify the Office host application for your reference:
[image]

You can refer to [here](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements) about more detail of host specifying in the manifest. And if you want to the Office add-in to support this feature, you can try to submit the feedback [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Although you cannot limit the platform, you CAN detect the platform that you are on programatically.

https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.html

Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.hostName

Will return Outlook, Mac Outlook or OutlookWebApp.

You could display an error message for the clients you don't want to support. Though this generally goes against a core principle of the platform of "write once, run anywhere"