# Office Addin - How to tell if loaded in web client or native

Tags: javascript, office365, office-addins

I'm working on an Office Add-In and need to be able to tell if the document was loaded in the standard Office software or Office365 Online.

I've checked the [docs](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/javascript-api-for-office) and can't find anything.

In [office.js](http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/ECFF3758/34EACEF4), there is an enumeration that looks as if it should be used somewhere, but i can't tell what property/event notifies us of the type. I have also stuck a breakpoint on the Office object and can't see anything.

```
Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.ApplicationMode={
WebEditor: "webEditor",
WebViewer: "webViewer",
Client: "client"
};
```

Does anyone know how to do this please?

Comment: I'm guessing from this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671721/disable-office-365-outlook-add-in-for-desktop) it's not possible. Will close this question.

Comment: Only Outlook add-ins have a way to detect if it's in OWA or the client

Answer (score 3):

I know this question was asked a long time ago, but it was something I was also looking for, and then stumbled upon the `Office.context` object, which gives me all the information I need about the hosting platform of the Office Add-in.

Some examples to follow...

### Calling `Office.context` on macOS, via Outlook `Desktop`:

```
{
  contentLanguage: "en-US"
  diagnostics: {
     host: "Outlook", 
     version: "16.47.314.0",
     platform: "Mac"
  },
  displayLanguage: "en-US",
  host: "Outlook",
  isDialog: false,
  platform: "Mac"
}
```

### Calling `Office.context` on macOS, via Outlook `Web`:

```
{
  contentLanguage: "",
  diagnostics: {
    host: "Outlook",
    platform: "OfficeOnline",
    version: "0.0.0.0"
  },
  displayLanguage: "en-US",
  host: "Outlook",
  isDialog: false,
  platform: "OfficeOnline"
}
```

So looking at the `platform` value is probably the most useful in your situation, where you can learn if this Add-in is being accessed via the web, mobile, desktop, etc.

---

**All of the possible `platform` values can be found here**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.platformtype?view=excel-js-preview

**The documentation for `Office.context` Interface can be found here**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.context?view=excel-js-preview#platform

Answer (score 2):

For reference, in Outlook you can use this to tell the difference between OWA or desktop or mac Outlook:

https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.html

Comment: Thanks for the info - Have upvoted. I'm working on PowerPoint, not Outlook, so might try Uservoice to see if something like this can be brought over.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for the same, but in my case for Word not Outlook, I just discovered that this code

```
        showNotification("url is: " + Office.context.document.url);
```

gives a URL something like this, in my case

```
        url is: https://<corp portal name>-my.sharepoint.com/personal/<my name>/Documents/Document15.docx
```

the number 15 is due to the fact I am currently up to 15 in-named documents in my OneDrive for Business folder (which is where these end up)

On a local client version of Word **URL** is blank.